# C#.NET/Genesys-How to retrieve certain value based on the event's ReferenceID

Tags: c#, .net, genesys

I'm not sure whether this is a good question to be asked here or should I say that this question is more to C#.NET or to Genesys.

I'm developing an agent desktop by using Genesys (contact center solution provider) Platform SDK and C#.NET. Basically when I request to send something to the server, if the request is successful, then an event will be returned, as shown in below.

```
'EventInfo' ('2')
message attributes:
REQ_ID [int]    = 402
USER_REQ_ID [int] = 0
TM_SERVER [int] = 1440495548
TM_LENGTH [int] = 1285
LONG_VALUE [int] = 0
STRING_VALUE [str] = "123"

'EventInfo' ('2')
message attributes:
REQ_ID [int]    = 301
USER_REQ_ID [int] = 0
TM_SERVER [int] = 1440495553
TM_LENGTH [int] = 1290
LONG_VALUE [int] = 0
STRING_VALUE [str] = "456"
```

Based on the events above, I sent two requests at the same time and therefore it returned two EventInfo. I can get the event's REQ_ID by `eventInfo.ReferenceID`, I can get the event's STRING_VALUE (which is the value that I want in this case and this value will be populate into a listview in my agent desktop) by `eventInfo.StringValue`.

My problem is how can I retrieve the string value based on the event's ReferenceID? Unfortunately, there is no such thing like: `eventInfo.ReferenceID(402).StringValue` and returns 123. Is there any similar way to get the value?

Comment: Can you post the code of where you are stuck?

Comment: Hi @EricScherrer, thanks for your comment. I solved my problem already, please have a look on the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this problem is more to C#. Here's how I solved my problem:

Firstly, I define a `dictionary` globally:

```
Dictionary<int, string> qInfoTempDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

The reason I used `dictionary` instead of `list` or `array` can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242526/how-to-search-duplicated-key-in-keyvaluepair-list-and-delete-the-earlier-key-val).

Next in my `EventInfo_Handler()` method, I wrote some statement like:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> sortedTempList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

//Whenever the EventInfo is received, quickly retrieve its ReferenceId and StringValue and store them in a temporary KeyValuePair dictionary
qInfoTempDict.Add(eventInfo.ReferenceId, eventInfo.StringValue);

//Sort the dictionary by ReferenceId
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> attribute in qInfoTempDict.OrderBy(key => key.Key))
        sortedTempList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(attribute.Key, attribute.Value));
```

Then insert the data into the listview accordingly.

Any feedback or enhancement on this solution is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you can spesify your request to which server, i'd like to help. There is lot of component on genesys platform. You can do whatever you want with that SDK. Even you can create 3rd party server acting like a core component in genesys.

Mainly genesys event-driven architecture. You must connect with proper config and client that defined on genesys CME. After that you can connect and listen events with platform SDK. SDK provides high abstraction to do this. After you create event listener like methods, assign your event methods to protocol event. After that you'll get events like other server & applications do. When you get a event on that method, cast it to what ever you like to see, on your case  you can cast it as EventInfo. Then you get the results.