# How to search duplicated key in KeyValuePair list and delete the earlier key value

Tags: c#, .net, list, keyvaluepair

I've a `KeyValuePair` list use to store some info from incoming message.

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> qInfoTempList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

qInfoTempList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(eventInfo.ReferenceId, eventInfo.StringValue));
```

Once the messages come in, the message's reference id stores as key and the message's selected value stores as value in the list. How can I detect a duplicated key on the spot and delete the earlier one in the list?

In this case, is it better to use `Dictionary` instead of `List`?

Comment: If you always want to remove the previous entry, then yes, it would be better to use a Dictionary than a List.

Comment: IMHO `Dictionary<,>` would be the obvious data structure of choice here, it does exactly what you seek for.

Comment: @Thorarins In this case he doesn't really need to search the list. Creating a mapping will be much easier, and faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want duplicates, you can use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, and check if the key exists using [`ContainsKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var infoById = new Dictionary<int, string>();
if (infoById.ContainsKey(someId))
{
    // Do override logic here
}
```

Or if you don't care about the previous item, you can simply replace it:

```
infoById[someId] = value;
```

Comment: Hi @YuvalItzchakov, thanks for your fast response. So if I use Dictionary, will the size of the Dictionary keep increasing when the messages come in? The key will be duplicated after first run and new key will not be produced.

Comment: @YWah Yes, it will resize dynamically as you insert records.